# CKFinder: PHP : InvalidCsrfTokenException: Invalid CSRF token

Tags: php, ckfinder

When I try to upload files I am getting the following error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught CKSource\CKFinder\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException: Invalid CSRF token. in D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\includes\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder.php:245
Stack trace:
```

This is new installation of ckfinder

Comment: the error tells you everything , you didn't pass the csrf token in your form

Comment: @madalinivascu  bro, but how to pass the csrf token. can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: i am not familiar with ckfinder, you should look that in the ckfinder documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution (although **not recommended**) is to disable CSRF protection in CKFinder. For PHP connector you can do this with [csrfProtection](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_csrfProtection) option by simply setting it to `false`:

```
 $config['csrfProtection'] = false;
```

The recommended way is to ask CKFinder to generate the CSRF token and use it when you submit your form (form field should be named `ckCsrfToken`):

```
var finder;

CKFinder.start({
    onInit: function(instance) {
        // Save finder instance to use it later
        finder = instance;
    }
});

// Later you can obtain the token the following way
console.log(finder.request('csrf:getToken'));
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread but how do you send it? The file upload is part of the PHP connector but I can't find any documentation on what to do with it once you get it from ckfinder.  (still unclear why this isn't just set up automatically when you turn on CSRF)

Comment: @Cfreak: By default, everything should work fine without any changes required here (CSRF token is automatically added on frontend and validated on backend). Problems like above may occur e.g. on cross-domain configurations. Here is a note in the docs: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/commands.html#commands_csrf_protection

If this doesn't help, can you please describe your issue with more details?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using a cross-domain configuration and getting errors. Most stuff works, just not uploads. It looks like I'm seeing a page linked now that I didn't catch before. Hopefully that points me in the right direction